# What is the overhead of increasing session timeout

Tags: asp.net, iis

I came across a scenario where my manager is asking me to increase the session timeout since a particular user is taking lot of time in providing details to make an order and thus loosing the session state by the time they place the order.

I am just wondering if there are going to be any repercussions for increasing session timeout since this is a application level setting not a page level setting

Answer (score 1):

1. Session timeout configuration depends on kind of website you are using. unless case of Payment or same product used by multiple users,you can set session timeout to whatever best suites for you.
   It may consume memory but is fine to increase.